# how to use i18n in pdf using itext in java

Tags: java, itext

I am using the Hindi language for displaying header content of table in pdf but it displaying empty cell in header part of table.

I have created like as follows:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);
writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));           
document.open();
PdfPTable lineItemTable = new PdfPTable(cellval);
lineItemTable.setHeaderRows(1);                
PdfPCell num1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("No",Bold_NORMAL)); 
num1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
num1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
lineItemTable.addCell(num1); 
PdfPCell lineval = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
lineval = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(HindiItenName,Bold_NORMAL));
lineval.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
lineval.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
lineItemTable.addCell(lineval);
document.add(lineItemTable);
document.close();            
response.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=ISO-8859-1");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Invoice-"+invNumber+".pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(buffer.toByteArray());
```

This is my sample code. Can you please help to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with struts

Comment: Does it work with English text? If so, what font is the text displayed in? (The font you are using here - and which I don't see mentioned anywhere - may not contain the characters required to draw your "Hindi language".)

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
writer.close();
document.close();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Closing the writer rounds of some structures in the document. But I have seen many examples where this is not done. So I am not sure.

The content type is for binary and does not need an encoding.

On the error: pick a Unicode font, IDENTITY_H:

```
final String FONT = "c:/windows/... .ttf";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
document.add(new Paragraph("Font: " + bf.getPostscriptFontName()
                + " with encoding: " + bf.getEncoding()));
```

Here an embedded font, so there will no problem at the recipient's side.
*This is from [itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=199), a book excerpt.*

For a better browser experience:

```
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for giving replay, but i got error as Error 500 access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "c:\windows\fonts\arialbd.ttf" "read") how i need to give filepermissions

Comment: Copy the font file into the application, or maybe better some Java EE server directory. But I seem to remember that itext tries a resource path too, so `/WEB-INF/arialdb.ttf` should do.

Comment: Maybe try a resource path "/arialbd.ttf": store the font file at the top level (maven: src/resources/main), so it comes in the .war as /WEB-INF/classes/arialbd.ttf. This is not really documented. What is documented: you may use the font _name_ for FONT.

Comment: hi, I have implement like below but pdf not createing it showing null   public static File fontFile = new File("arialuni.ttf"); BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
document.add(new Paragraph("hello text",new Font(bf,20)));second row only problem i didn't get how to fix can u please help me

Comment: Sorry then I am lost. One could first create a local test application to develop the code. And work from there towards a solution. At the end place it in the servlet (not JSP).